# Query Table with SQL statement and get results to another Table

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

In VBA I want to query one Excel table using SQL statements and get the results to another Excel table. I need some direction to what to read because I am confused. Excuse me for asking many different questions in one post at once, but the questions cover one subject.

- **The source table.** How should I find out if the source data is a query table or ListObject table (excuse me for ignorance, if calling it ListObjects table is not a proper way). What is the difference between QueryTables and ListObjects tables? [This explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067070/excel-vba-refer-to-querytable-objects-by-name) has not shed light on it.
- How to get the proper **connection string** to existing table (be it a QueryTable or ListObject table)?
- What is the benefit of using **ADO** to do the job? If I get the idea with ADO, we make a self connection to the source table in Excel (correct me if I am wrong). This link  [Query Tables (QueryTables) in Excel 2010 with VBA with VBA creating many connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926441/query-tables-querytables-in-excel-2010-with-vba-with-vba-creating-many-connect) shows that ADO is not necessery, while this one argues that using it is good: http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/beyond-excel/say-goodbye-to-querytables/

The code below (grabbed from [here](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2008/06/24/create-a-querytable-from-an-excel-source-in-vba/)) looks simple and promissing:

```
Sub idee()
  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
  With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(“ODBC;DSN=Excel-bestanden;DBQ=E:TheDatabook.xls”,[H1])
    .CommandText = “SELECT name, number FROM TheData WHERE number =1″
    .Refresh False
  End With
End Sub
```

However I would like to use there proper connection string (replacing this: `ODBC;DSN=Excel-bestanden;DBQ=E:TheDatabook.xls`) and replace named range TheData with QueryTable or ListObject table and I would like to get the output to QueryTable or ListObject table.

Comment: You need to reverse that, so activesheet.querytables(1).commandtext for exampe or activesheet.querytables(1).refresh to refresh it.   ADO benefits would be the data in an a more controllable object, you can have a 0 check on your refresh to say whether anything returned, triggers off the refresh when new items added/deleted, filtering, finding etc. Finding out information about database, show tables/queries etc,  Reading about ADO would be best, as everyone will use differently in their life, too much to write :)

Comment: I ended up using the idea presented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33807584/1903793